# Alternatives libraries for loading PNG images

Tags: java, png, transparency, loading

My java J2SE application is reading a lot of (png) images from the web and some of them use features such as a transparency color for true-color images (tRNS section) that Sun's/Oracle's PNGImageReader implementation simply ignores.

Therefore the common solution for loading via `ImageIO.read(...);` does not work for me as it relies on this incomplete PNGImageReader implementation.

Does anybody know a png reader implementation that can read all forms of PNG images correctly - those with color table or true-color and alpha transparency or transparent color?

As it is for a GPL project it should be a non-commercial one that can be included without licensing problems into the app.

**Edit:** My be this question was too specific. Therefore let be redesign my question:

**Who knows alternative implementations and libraries that are able to load PNG files?**

I will then test the implementations for their capabilities to load some [test png images](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/pngtest/).

**Edit2:** The end result have to be a BufferedImage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found a suitable PNG reader which fits my needs perfectly:

[Sixlegs Java PNG Decoder](http://code.google.com/p/javapng/)

Main features:

- Open Source (LGPL)
- Loads PNG correctly including alpha
  transparency and transparent colors
- Returns a BufferedImage
- Has no further dependencies to other
  libraries
- Has a very small size (46KB for the whole library).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the Apache Commons [Imaging](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/) library?  The PNG support is specified as:

> Supported through version 1.2/ISO/IEC
>   standard (15948:2003). Controlling the
>   exact format when writing is
>   incomplete.

Being a pure Java library, it should work well on J2SE.

Comment: Link is dead. I believe this is the correct current URL: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to acquire the image:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(theFilenameOfTheImage)
```

**Edit:**
If you need a BufferedImage, you can use the following:

```
ImageIcon iic=new ImageIcon(theFilenameOfTheImage);
BufferedImage bimg=((ToolkitImage)iic.getImage()).getBufferedImage();
```

It basically loads the image the same way, but the ImageIcon class is using a MediaTracker to make sure the image is fully loaded. This way, you can access the resulting BufferedImage, and it will always contain the pixmap.

Comment: First I thought that this can not work as it will use the same image reader internally. Funnily this really works - the transparency is correctly loaded but the returned image is a sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage but I need a java.awt.image.BufferedImage. The common approach of creating a new BufferedImage and drawing the ToolkitImage on it does not work for an unknown reason (no exception).