# Array index error when duplicating a BufferedImage

Tags: java, arrays, image

So I'm trying to keep two copies of a set of images cached in my program. I've got an object that holds both references in it and a loop that loads the images and passes them to a new instance of that particular class. However, on about the 25th iteration, I get an Array Index Out of Bounds Exception when the class makes the copy. I've deduced that its trying to either copy to a non-existent pixel in the second copy or it's going beyond the bounds of the first copy.

Here's the parts of the code that matter:

The Loop:

```
Hashtable<String, Sheet> tempHashTable = new Hashtable<String, Sheet>();
for(int ii = 0; ii < sheetNames.size(); ii++) {
   try {
      File tempSheetFile = new File(Constants.TEMP_DIR, sheetNames.get(ii));
      BufferedImage tempSheet = ImageIO.read(tempSheetFile);
      System.out.println(sheetNames.get(ii));
      tempHashTable.put(sheetNames.get(ii), new Sheet(tempSheet));
   } catch (IOException ex) {
   }
}
```

Sheet Init:

```
private BufferedImage defaultSheet;
private BufferedImage currentSheet;

public Sheet(BufferedImage defaultSheet) {
    this.defaultSheet = defaultSheet;
    currentSheet = new BufferedImage(defaultSheet.getWidth(), defaultSheet.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    currentSheet.setData(defaultSheet.getData()); //Error line
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 64
```

The weirdest part about it is that the second BufferedImage is created with the size of the first, so why would we ever get an array index exception?

**Edit**: Alright, so I switched `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB` to `defaultSheet.getType()` and the error's gone. The problem now is that the same images that were giving me the error before are now showing up inside the program without their red and alpha channels that definitely exist in the source files.

**Edit**: Never attribute to glitches what can be adequately explained by horrible programming. New code has the constructor load the image twice rather than copying an existing instance's data. Much cleaner, though I am using the `javapng` library available here http://code.google.com/p/javapng/

Comment: `currentSheet = new BufferedImage(defaultSheet.getWidth(), defaultSheet.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);`  What image type is the current (`defaultSheet`) image?

Comment: Well, it's loaded from a PNG using ImageIO.read() in the loop so I was assuming ARGB. As mentioned by @cgull in the answers, I switched BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB to defaultSheet.getType(). However, now I'm finding out that my program is only loading what appears to be the blue and green channels of some images (yeah, they definitely have red and alpha channels). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the line to the following in your `Sheet` constructor:

```
currentSheet = new BufferedImage(defaultSheet.getWidth(), defaultSheet.getHeight(), defaultSheet.getType());
```

Comment: Thanks so much @cgull, that worked like a charm. Which is interesting; would you happen to know why a png wouldn't result in an ARGB image type?

Comment: Is it possible that the png in question has no alpha channel?

Comment: Well, looking at the actual file that it's reading from there's definitely an alpha channel. However, looking at the image once it's loaded into my program there's a definite problem: Some of the images (at least one of which is the one I was having a problem with earlier) seem to be lacking both their alpha and red channels. Very odd...

Comment: It could point to a bug in `ImageIO` that is not loading some pngs properly; it's not unheard of, as this bug report shows: http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6703368

Comment: Hmmm. Do you know of an alternate image loading lib for Java by chance? The workaround listed on that link... yeah, kind of speaks for itself.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443288/alternatives-libraries-for-loading-png-images