# ImageIO.read -> Error reading PNG image data

Tags: java, exception, zip, png, javax.imageio

I get an `InputStream` input, and I want to read this `InputStream`.

I create a

```
BufferedImage image = null;
```

And I read with `ImageIO` :

```
read image = ImageIO.read(input);
```

This code works for JPEG and JPG files but, with PNG files I have this error :

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Error reading PNG image data    at
com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readImage(PNGImageReader.java:1308)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.read(PNGImageReader.java:1577)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1448)    at
javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1352)   at
org.projectsforge.swap.proxy.simulation.DichromacyImageSimulation.handle(DichromacyImageSimulation.java:64)
    at org.projectsforge.swap.proxy.proxy.ProxyServlet$1.execute(ProxyServlet.java:150)
    at org.projectsforge.swap.proxy.proxy.ProxyServlet$1.execute(ProxyServlet.java:1)
    at org.projectsforge.swap.core.handlers.HandlerExecutorManager.execute(HandlerExecutorManager.java:72)
    at org.projectsforge.swap.core.handlers.HandlerContext$1.run(HandlerContext.java:175)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back
    at
java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)   
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)  
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)   
at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:195)  
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.decodePass(PNGImageReader.java:1092)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.decodeImage(PNGImageReader.java:1207)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readImage(PNGImageReader.java:1301)
    ... 8 more
```

I don't understand this error, especially because this error does not happen every time...

Comment: Please use code formatting on code segments and stack traces.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button.

Comment: I create input like that : InputStream input; and I filled the content : input = Content.getInputStream();     In fact, my code is part of an existing project. Method "getInputStream" is already implemented and working properly.

Comment: `Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException:` Are these images being read from a Zip or a Jar or something else?

Comment: Make sure to add @NikolayKuznetsov  (or whoever) to notify them of a new comment.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2)  I would try loading the PNG from `URL`, rather than `InputStream`.

Comment: If the image may be shown around, I think some will want to try reading the image itself. I would look whether other image editors (GIMP) do have problems, or whether they can save it differently. To search for the cause. For [alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443288/alternatives-libraries-for-loading-png-images).

Comment: The most probable cause is a corrupt image. Did you created it? Can you read it with some other software?